# Does react have built in formatters like Angular?

Tags: reactjs

Like the ones here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter

I found these extremely useful while using Angular and I'd hope that I don't have to come up with my own implementation in React

Comment: There is no such concept in react at all, so "no".

Comment: It's not obvious though, why you even need those: you can, say, turn a string to upper case with `String.prototype.toUpperCase()` without any additional redundant concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no it doesn't. But you can get there with simple logic in the render function or elsewhere.